# Configuring Red Hat as Domain Controller to get the ticket of kerberos authentication from windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, kerberos, samba

I configure the windows 2008 as Exchange2010 server, which has domain Example.com, and the other  Windows 7 client as Exchange2010 client. The Server IP address is 192.168.0.76 , meanwhile the client IP address is 192.168.0.176.

We all know that, when the the client request to the Exchange2010 server, we can configure it through kerberos authentication. The client can get the Ticket from the KDC of Windows 2008. For further detail, the Client can get the encrypted Service_key through the TGS_REP message of kerberos from the KDC of Windows 2008.

Under these circumstances, I have an idea is that we configure Red Hat Linux as Domain Controller in my organisation to get the encrypted Service_key. The Red Hat Linux ip address is 192.168.0.149. The Red Hat Linux used as Domain Controller, which has the function of KDC instead of the function of Windows 2008 server’s KDC.

My first question is that is that is my idea feasible? Or if it not feasible, how can I get the service_key?

My Second question is that the Red Hat Linux has samba installed, and the samba can used as domain controller, how can samba get the synchronize user’s informations as well as password and Ticket informations from Windows Server2 008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain controller functionality which Exchange 2010 expects can only be provided by an Active Directory Domain Controller. RHEL as it is cannot provide it with the Samba version that is available on RHEL. Please note that Exchange 2010 server expects more than just Kerberos KDC from a domain controller.

Samba project implements AD DC-like functionality starting with Samba 4.0. There are some details as to implementation; in particular, Samba 4.x cannot yet to be compiled with MIT Kerberos KDC (available on RHEL) to provide AD DC-like setup. The version of samba4 packages in RHEL 6.x is only suitable for using with FreeIPA identity management solution (which cannot yet be used to host Exchange server).

The only other solution would be to compile and configure Samba 4.x by yourself, using embedded Heimdal Kerberos KDC, as described http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO. However, this configuration would fall outside of a supported RHEL setup, at least for my understanding.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me. Thank you.
By your reply, I still has two questions:
Firstly, just as you said “Exchange 2010 server expects more than just Kerberos KDC from a domain controller.” My question is that “what Exchange2010 server expects in detail?”
 Secondly, After I configured the RHEL as AD DC, can it used as KDC for Exchange2010 client identity authentication? My ultimate goal is get the function interface of service_key and ticket, Can I get it?

Comment: Exchange expects Active Directory domain controller functionality. It is a lot to describe, you may look at corresponding Microsoft documentation, for example, at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780036%28WS.10%29.aspx#w2k3tr_ad_over_qbjd for short introduction.

Comment: If you deploy Samba AD DC with the HOWTO outlined in my answer, it can be used for Exchange client identity authentication. Since AD DC role in Samba is still under heavy development, make sure you are using sufficiently recent version (4.1 at this time)

Comment: I have successfully configured, the client (windows2003) can join Samba domain of redhat5.5.Next, I want to do is how to get the keys and tickets from kerberos authentication in the samba source code.

Comment: There are still many issues to address as follow：                   1, The structure of samba source code;                             2, The part relavate with kerberos authentication code in the samba source code;                                                       3, How to narrow the range to find the source code and service_key related function call interface?                                       I would like to hear your point of view, many thanks to you! @abbra

Comment: I think you are mixing unrelated things altogether and development-specific questions are not really what needs to be focused on. Setting up an AD DC-compatible domain controller is one thing. Enrolling a Windows server and installing Exchange 2010 on it. At this point things should work. If you are interested in actual Samba source code analysis, you need to join samba-technical@ mailing list at lists.samba.org and start asking specific questions there. These development-specific questions are not related to the deployment as you describe it at all.

Comment: You pointed out are very correct, I will humbly receive your suggestions. Now my problem is mainly focused on:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001395/how-to-get-service-key-and-the-corresponding-function-call-interface-from-the-sa. I have already  ask questions.through  e-mail ur group your mentioned. Thank you very much!@abbra

Comment: My new description of the problem is http://serverfault.com/questions/555720/get-service-key-in-the-course-of-kerberos-authentication

Comment: please help me answer about ideas @abbra